# SharePoint migrating domains

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory, migration, cross-domain

I need to migrate our SharePoint farm to a new domain.  Until everything is moved we have full trust set up between the domains.

Farm Hardware

One WFE/Index Server

Two SQL DB Servers (clustered)

I know how to do this using all new hardware from production to a dev environment but doing an in place migration seems more daunting.  To take some of the pressure off we have a new beefy SharePoint box to install to that will be a fresh box on the new domain but we don't have enough hardware to have a separate SQL cluster.

I am told that all the boxes should be on the same domain so now the hard part is to bring the SQL box on the new domain.  Can I just switch domains on the SQL DB cluster and then install SP on the new WFE?

Comment: You should ask this question on ServerFault.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voted to move to serverfault, but here's my 2 cents. Moving SQL Server 2 a new domain is easy, sql server will pick up any changes. The problem is sharepoint. SharePoint users to be exact. 
Any documents in your site(s) will have it's created by / modified by broken, because even though the same users exist in the new domain, the bindings will be incorrect, sharepoint expects for instance user userA@olddomain.local, which is very different from user userA@newdomain.local. There is a way around this using httpmodules etc, but it is a pain in the ass.

Check out the result when googling **migrate sharepoint new domain**.

Comment: Our users have been moved to the new domain using ADMT but they are still loggin into the old domain.  The will "migrated" in batches and told they are to start using the new domain.  when this happens I am thinking I need to run the  stsadm migrateuser command for those users.  My next question is when I move my servers to the new domain should I run ADMT on my sharepoint admin accounts and use the new domain sharepoint accounts ?

Answer (score 0):

I've run a similar setup before.  If they're full trust, you should be able to reconnect to your pre-existing config/content dbs from the new SharePoint instance in the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

- SQL server 
  You can have your SQL server in a different domain as long as there is a trust between the domains.
- Migrating users
  With regards to migrating your users, it's a daunting task because those user's SIDS own objects, I've used stsadm -o migrateuser but it's not terribly helpful, I'd consider looking into 3rd party software such as DocAve who have products that assist in migrating SharePoint content.  If you really want to hack it, break open the Users table in your content databases and write a script to update the usernames and sids.

Comment: This is not supported I know this is an old post, but I came across it so others might as well. Microsoft does not support running T-SQL Scripts against the SharePoint Databases, this is why they gave us the SharePoint Admin Shell Console and STSADM in older versions, your best bet would be to rebuild new servers in the new domain.